# Write linux script to convert timestamps older than 1.1.1970 to 2.2.1970

Tags: linux, shell, date, timestamp

I am unable to sync my files with Owncloud because some timestamps are earlier that 1.1.1970, the Unix start of time convention.

Anybody knows how to write a script that finds all files with timestamps earlier than 1.1.1970 and converts them to any date after 1.1.1970, perhaps 1.1.1980?

Thanks

Best

Comment: did you try `touch -t "198001011000" *.*`

Answer (score 2):

You could try this (tested on GNU/Linux system)

```
touch -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00" /tmp/timestamp
find / -not -cnewer /tmp/timestamp -exec touch {} \;
```

This is a version which compatible with POSIX.1:

```
touch -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00" /tmp/timestamp
find / ! -newer /tmp/timestamp -exec touch {} \;
```

See [touch](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html) and [find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html).

Comment: Thanks. It replies Touch: non valid option -- "n"

Comment: @user3428634 Where does that "n" come from? Anyway, please refer to your `touch(1)` to find out how to create a file with specific modification time.

Comment: +1, note though that [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) does not specify `-not` so you will want to use `!` to negate an expression instead (e.g. `! -cnewer ...`).

Answer (score 0):

To touch on the timestamp on those files, use the below. Then try to run RSYNC

```
touch -t "198001011000" *.*
```

Amended as per OP's request

```
find <dir> -not -newermt 1970-01-01 -exec touch -t '198001011000' {} \;
```

or simply

```
find <dir> -not -newermt 1970-01-01 -exec touch {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks This seems very good to change the timestamp to the new one. But I cannot change the timestamp of ALL files. Rather only of those that are older than 01.01.1970.

Comment: You can use find command to search all files older than a certain date and use either xargs or exec tool to apply this touch

Comment: I have two commands that work:

Quote:
find . *.* -not -newermt 1970-01-01
and

Quote:
touch -t "198001011000" *.*
But I do not know how to chain them so the the output of the first goes to the second. I tried:

Quote:
find . *.* -not -newermt 1970-01-01 | xargs touch -t "198001011000"
But I get an error for each file:

file or directory non existent

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to work when launched in the folder where you want to correct dates. It will automatically work in all eventual subfolders:

```
find . *.*  -not -newermt 1970-01-01 -exec touch -t "198001011000" {} \;
```

Best